# Is it possible to have Craft send an email on page load?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, emails

I'm very new to this so any guidance is greatly appreciated. I've written a couple of simple plugins that will send an email to admins on new user save and and on new entry creation. What I need to do now is to send a weekly email with all new entries created in the last 7 days to a particular user group. I figured it'd be pretty efficient to set up an online CRON job to hit a site url, and on load of that page, trigger my email plugin. However, I'm not sure how to trigger my plugin on page load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think you would want to instead set up a controller action, as URLs route directly to them, rather than use the overhead of a page.

Your cron job could hit the corresponding Controller Action URL (i.e., http://mysite.com/actions/myplugin/entriescreated/weekly), and run your job like that. Note, where you're accessing an action via cron you would have to set it to allow anonymous access to the action.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers

Comment: Took me a minute to wade through that, but I got it. All working!!! Thanks!

Comment: Question. I tested by just physically going to the action url. It returned a 404 page on the site. Is there a way to precent action urls from doing this?

Comment: You'll need to trigger some sort of response to keep it from doing this: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/controller-action-works-but-still-gives-404